Horizontal drywall cracks - stairwell - what could cause it?



Hey all - roughly a 30 year old house. Noticed these thin cracks forming on the sides of the stairs. Didn’t notice cracks anywhere else. The basement / garage is surrounded by soil on 3 sides. It does get more humid than the rest of the house, so not sure if drywall is expanding / contracting at different rates.
Fairly new to the house so haven’t seen it before.

In the first pic I see mesh tape showing through the compound.  My thought is it's just a bad tape and mud job. If that is done poor the drywall sheet may be installed poorly as well. ( to few screws.)

Thanks for the reply!

@RMDman  I stopped using mesh tape for exactly that reason

What do you guys recommend using instead of mesh tape to repair this?

In my opinion this is not a repair that needs tape. This is a fill in the crack, sand , primer and paint job.
